# unable to show a listbox having a fixed height in Tkinter

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I am trying to insert a listbox inside a frame in my hypertext program.
This listbox starts up empty, but during usage should display one or more items.
I'd like to give to it a fixed height (say 8 items) and use the scrollbar to see more of them.

I boiled down the code to the following - if you run it you'll see that the program doesnt obey the 'height=8' request...

what am I missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (1420,840))
root.title("inFolder")

configtext = Text(root, width=150)
yscrollbar=Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=configtext.yview)
configtext["yscrollcommand"]=yscrollbar.set

auxframe=Frame(root)
chtext = Text(auxframe, width=50)
chxscrollbar=Scrollbar(chtext, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=chtext.xview)
chtext["xscrollcommand"]=chxscrollbar.set
chxscrollbar.pack(side="bottom",fill="x", expand=False)

# --------------- searchframe ----------
searchframe=Frame(auxframe)
encasef=Frame(searchframe)
encasef.pack()
sfe1 = Entry(encasef,width=30)
sfe1.pack(side=LEFT)
sfnocase = Checkbutton(encasef, text="Case")
sfnocase.pack()
sfsearchresultsbox = Listbox(searchframe,height=8)
sfsearchresultsbox.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
sfsb = Scrollbar(sfsearchresultsbox, orient=VERTICAL, command=sfsearchresultsbox.yview)
sfsb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
sfsearchresultsbox['yscrollcommand'] = sfsb.set


# GRID
auxframe.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky=E+W+S+N)       
searchframe.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky=E+W+S+N)       
chtext.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=E+W+S+N)       
configtext.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=E+W+S+N)                
yscrollbar.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=N+S)

Grid.columnconfigure(root,0,weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root,1,weight=0)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)   
auxframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
auxframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

configtext.insert(INSERT,"test 1\ntest 2\ntest 3\ntest 4\n\ntest x\n")

#------------------------------
mainloop()
```

Comment: according to: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm
You need to define pack a `yscrollcommand` and then include it in your `Listbox`

Comment: yes, it's just done differently by the sfsearchresultsbox['yscrollcommand'] = sfsb.set command... but the scrollbar works - my problem is the default height that is always == 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are packing a scrollbar *inside* the listbox (and also inside your text box). This is not something you should do -- the scrollbars need to live outside the widgets they are controlling.

Because you pack the scrollbar inside the listbox, the pack geometry manager now controls the width and the height of the listbox, causing it to shrink down to exactly fit its contents. You can turn geometry propagation off for the listbox (`sfsearchresultsbox.pack_propagate(False)`) but that's not a proper solution. The real fix is to move the scrollbars outside of the widgets they contain.

Besides the geometry issue, the other problem with packing scrollbars inside the widgets that they control is that the scrollbars will sit on top of any data in the widgets. The horizontal scrollbars, for example, will obscure the last visible line.

If you want the scrollbars to appear to be inside the borders of the listbox, give the listbox a borderwidth of 0 (zero), then place the listbox and scrollbar inside a frame with a borderwidth of 1 (one). You get the same visual effect without the problems associated with packing the scrollbar inside the widget.

Comment: just what I needed, thank you! I created a Frame containing both the listbox and the scrollbar, and that took care of everything